# cascading Multiple lookup field?

Tags: sharepoint

I used cascading lookup field custom control from

http://jaypoint.com/sharepoint-cascading-lookup-field-jquery/

when I create a field from this custom type its type becomes **cascading lookup**

I want to set it to be multiple lookup column

I changed the parenttype of the field to be LookupMulti

and in code when I allow multiple values I found that the type of the field changed from **cascading lookup** to standard **lookup field** which leads to loss of functionality.

is there any way to do this without changing the type of the fieled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

I got it. the solution is to modify the schema.xml of the file to force it keep the type of the custom field.

i got it from here http://chrisforbesblogs.net/tag/lookupmulti/

he had the same scenario

Answer (score 0):

I would just recommend using a commercial solution, such as our [Connected Field](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=ConnectedFields2007)
It supports single and multiple parent/child, multiple children chaining, site columns, content type and inline choice entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a third party solution,please try our [SharePoint Cascaded Lookup)](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint-cascaded-site-lookup) ,a simple but powerful add-ons for sharepoint ,and relatively cheap($299/WFE)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

Change the settings to 'Allow Multiple value Select' in the lookup column.

Then use the below code in the script

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns
({ relationshipList: "Display Name of Master List", relationshipListParentColumn: "Parent Column Internal Name from Master List", relationshipListChildColumn: "Child Column Internal Name from Master List", parentColumn: "Parent Column Display Name from List/Library", childColumn: "Child Column Display Name from List/Library" });

For child Column call the column with the 'Title' of lookup field instead of 'ID'